# Is it possible to have a link to appController action in cakephp 3?

Tags: url, cakephp-3.0

Can I do something like

```
//appController
public function showHelp() {
    echo "Show help";
}

//layout
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#helptext').click(function(){
        $.post("<?= $this->Url->build(['controller'=>'app' , "action" => "showHelp"]) ?>",function(data){
            $('#helptext').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Or I must using cells for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask whether it works? Answer is works.

If your question is whether it is efficient. Answer is its depends on your application structure. (What you intend to achieve)

Your above code will work. showHelp() should be as follows

```
//appController
public function showHelp() {
    echo "Show help";
exit;
}
```

Comment: Add an exit at the end of showHelp() in your appcontroller. It should work